# "add content" suddenly not showing on navigation block anymore

Tags: 7, routes, nodes, users, navigation

Good day,
I'm having a problem of a block not showing its content!
the block is stock and called navigation, which has "add content" in its links.

but just recently, it has not been working on other users except admin.
i checked it setting, and the access control says: "authenticated users" which is good.
but the moment i check it at other users (the non admin), i can only see the navigation block with "chaos Ajax demo" ONLY..

i checked around possible permissions, link settings, but with no luck..nothing seemed strange to me..

here's a screen shot of the navigation block at admin:
[image: nav. bar at admin]
and here's 2nd shot at non admin (was working and showing few days back, but then suddenly became like this):
[image: nav. bar at local user]

logically speaking, since the navigation block is existing at other users only means that its permissions is allowed for users to see the block.

but why suddenly it stopped showing the links?? im very much concerned about "add content" link, because i need it to add contents (otherwise, i'll have to go through a headache of creating 10s of manual links for each content to add).

let me note that I'm quit new to drupal, that's why I'm not pretty sure what did i mess with here.

any help is very appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a clarification about terminology: make sure to correctly separate access to "blocks" from "navigation links": your non admin users seem to have access to that "block" also (that Ajax link in it proofs that to me). Your real issue/question should be something like "why are some of the menu links missing in that block?".

Seems like you need to resolve that "Access Denied" message first. Even though it's hard to tell (from the screenshots provided), My best guess would be that you need to review/tune some of the settings related to "node" within `admin/people/permissions`.

So check/confirm that for the users who receive this "Access Denied", they are granted the permission like "View Published Content". If that permission was not granted yet, then do so now and try again to see what happens.

A few more "comments" (moved from the comments below to around here):

- The "menu items" that are shown in that block, will be shown (only) to the users who have access to the actual content (node) that the menu items are related to. And apart from that there is the "block visibility", which is typically something you "can" set so that it is only shown (or hidden) on specific pages, or so that it is only shown to users with specific roles.
- About "I didn't want every user to other users' published content": looks like there is something you mis-interprete about the "View published content": that permission is ONLY a way to tell Drupal "which roles are allowed to see anything (nodes) that have the "published" checkbox turned on. It seems to me that you MIGHT need to add something like the (great!) "[Content_Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)" module to implement something similar to what you wrote in one of your last comments.
- If it makes sense, you should set the "default" content access for each content type first, so that you only have to change it for those nodes where you want content access to be different from that default. So no need to "go through every content to manage their content access".

Comment: what on earth?  my salute for @Pierre !!
i very surprised, how come not giving access to view publish content was affecting the navigation menu, i mean shouldn't they be not related? because i didn't want every user to other users' published contents.

Comment: First things first: no need for "sir" around here, just "Pierre" is fine, ok?

Comment: no problemo..
yes, i guess thats the issue im wondering about..how do separate the access to blocks for the links themselves?

Comment: ooh, i see!! ..yes i do understand, i just knew about the content access recently actually (in my previous question about the admin restriction reasons)..
i just tested what u advised, and it worked!! it seems that i have to go through every content to manage their content access control and make them "view own content only" .. my issue is addressed to the bulls' eye! thank you very much. :D